# How to change Bootstrap tab by pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am new to bootstrap and jQuery. I have created a bootstrap Tab, which is working fine. The tabs are changing by header, but I also needs pagination to change Tab, which I am not able to do. Following is my scenario,

```
Tab 1 --> next button --> go to tab 2
Tab 1  <-- previous -- Tab 2 -- next ---> Tab 3
Tab 2  <-- previous -- Tab 3
```

Can any one help. Following is my HTML. This is just an example, I can have variable number of tabs.

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- tabs -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-alternate">
            <li>
                <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Question - 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Question - 2 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Question - 3 </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- tabs content -->
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <div class="tab-content tab-stacked nav-alternate">
            <div id="tab_1" class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Some Text Tab 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="next"><a class="radius-0" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Next &rarr;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tab_2" class="tab-pane">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Some Text Tab 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="pager">
                   <li class="previous"><a class="radius-0" href="#">&larr; Previous</a></li>
                   <li class="next"><a class="radius-0" href="#">Next &rarr;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tab_3" class="tab-pane">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Some Text Tab 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="pager">
                   <li class="previous"><a class="radius-0" href="#">&larr; Previous</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Updated jQuery script to attach to the previouse/next link.
2. Updated `class="active"` to the `li` tag for Question-1.

   ```
   <!-- tabs -->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-alternate">
           <li class="active">
               <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Question - 1 </a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Question - 2 </a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">Question - 3 </a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>

   <!-- tabs content -->
   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
       <div class="tab-content tab-stacked nav-alternate">
           <div id="tab_1" class="tab-pane active">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <p>Some Text Tab 1</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <ul class="pager">
                 <li class="next"><a class="radius-0" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Next &rarr;</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div id="tab_2" class="tab-pane">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <p>Some Text Tab 2</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="previous"><a class="radius-0" href="#">&larr; Previous</a></li>
                  <li class="next"><a class="radius-0" href="#">Next &rarr;</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div id="tab_3" class="tab-pane">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                   <div class="panel-body">
                       <p>Some Text Tab 3</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="previous"><a class="radius-0" href="#">&larr; Previous</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   ```
   <script>
       $('.next').click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
       });

       $('.previous').click(function(){
           $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
       });
   </script>
   ```